# Question on finite representation theory of cyclic group $C_n$

Tags: representation-theory

My professor wrote in his notes that a one-dimensional representation of the cyclic group $C_n$ with $a$ as a generator could be written as follows.

$\phi_m(a^k)=e^{2\pi imk/n}$ for some $k \in \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ and $m$ is also some integer (not further specified in notes). This is quite clear for me, we can easily check that this is a representation since it is a homomorphism.

But now he defines a two-dimensional representation as the direct sum $\phi_1 \oplus \phi_{-1}$ given by the following matrix:

$(\phi_1 \oplus \phi_{-1})(a^k) = diag(e^{2\pi ik/n},e^{-2\pi ik/n})$ so a diagonal matrix with the one-dimensional representations on the diagonal.

In representation theory we always want a homomorphism given by:

$\phi : G \rightarrow GL(V) \cong Mat(n,K)$ where $V$ is the representation space over a field $K$ and because we are dealing with finite vector spaces we can always identify a linear map $\phi \in GL(V)$ with a matrix $\textbf{given a basis}$ to get $\phi \in Mat(n,K)$.

My question is: with respect to what basis is this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter with respect to what basis it is. It doesn't even matter with respect to what vector space it is. For instance, you could have a representation of $C_n$ on the set of all complex-valued functions on $S_2$, and the basis could consist of the functions given by the symmetric and the antisymmetric character on $S_2$. What matters is that the matrices have the same multiplication law as the group elements; the underlying vector space is arbitrary and ultimately irrelevant.

Having said that, I suspect that your professor perhaps had the canonical basis for $\mathbb C^2$ in mind.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. After this there was a remark that $span\{e_1\}$ and $span\{e_2\}$ form invariant subspaces, so I think the standard basis is assumed. I understand that it does not matter with respect to what basis the matrix is as long as $\phi : G \rightarrow Mat(n,K)$ is a homomorphism. But what I do not understand is that the basis would be irrelevant since when we determine e.g. eigenvectors of a matrix we have to know the basis or do we not care about this since we can define a isomorphism between a basis and the standard basis?

Comment: @dani: Are you talking about eigenvectors of the matrix or of the linear map that it represents? The eigenvectors of the matrix are simply column vectors of numbers, we don't need a basis to find them. If you meant the eigenvectors of the linear map, then yes, we'd need to know the basis to get from the eigenvectors of the matrix to the eigenvectors of the map, but then the question would again be why we would want to do that. If we're dealing with a concrete representation, this might be relevant, but if we're just studying the possible representations of the group, it isn't.

Comment: I was talking about the eigenvectors of the matrix. So what you mean that for example for some representation we have $(1 1)^T$ as an eigenvector this just contains the coefficients with respect to some basis, which you do not explicitly state? My confusion is really that it states that $span\{e_1\}$, $span\{e_2\}$ form invariant subspaces of $\mathcal{C}^2$. I would prefer $span\{(1 0)^T\}$ and $span\{(0 1)^T\}$ since I do not know whether the basis is really the standard basis. If I know that yeah then of course we can specify it further but my professor did not show that he uses this basis.

Comment: @dani: It's hard to say something reliable about this without knowing the entire context and how your professor introduced these things, but as far as I can tell from what you write, it seems he got it exactly right. It doesn't matter what the basis is, we can just call it $\{e_1,e_2\}$, and a map whose representation for this basis is diagonal has invariant subspaces $\operatorname{span}\{e_1\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{e_2\}$. I guess you could say that the matrix itself has "invariant subspaces" $\operatorname{span}\{(10)^\top\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{(01)^\top\}$, ...

Comment: ... but usually we talk about the invariant subspaces of the map (which are subspaces of the vector space carrying the representation), not the "invariant subspaces" of the matrix (which are subspaces of the space of column vectors, which isn't really an object we usually consider in its own right). But I'm not sure your professor is worrying all that much about this distinction; I wouldn't be surprised if he sometimes blurs the line between column vectors that the matrix operates on and vectors that the map operates on, which might as well also be column vectors.

Comment: But why can you just call the basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$? I mean you can see from the matrix that the eigenvectors are formed by span$\{(1 0)^T\}$ and span$\{(0 1)^T\}$. But the coefficients in the columns are with respect to some basis, which is not necessarily the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ but some ordered basis $\{a_1,a_2\}$. A step is missing here, I think you made use of the isomorphism between the standard basis and the ordered basis as follows $\{a_1,a_2\} \cong \{e_1,e_2\}$ ? I understand it is hard to answer for you since you don't know the context, but I tried to formulate it well.

Comment: It is very common to identify $e_1$ and $e_2$ with $(10)^T$ and $(01)^T$ when the context does not supply a reason to be mindful about the difference between the underlying vector space and the coordinates of its vectors with respect to some given basis. The professor may as well be saying: choose a basis at will. Define $(\phi_1 \oplus \phi_{-1})(a^k)$ as the transformation whose matrix w.r.t. this basis is $diag(e^{2\pi i k / n}, e^{-2\pi i k / n})$. The choice of basis is immaterial because two representations are considered *equivalent* if there is an isomorphism between the underlying...

Comment: vector spaces that carries the action of the group on one space to the action on the other. Here, that's what happens between any pair of choices you might make. If we start with the same 2d vector space $V$, and you choose basis $a_1,a_2$ while I choose basis $b_1,b_2$, and we both do what your professor said, then we get technically distinct definitions for $\phi_1\oplus\phi_{-1}$, but they are equivalent because the automorphism $V\rightarrow V$ carrying $a_i\mapsto b_i$ transforms one into the other.

Comment: I understand what you just explained and it makes sense, but there is still one point I cannot grasp. Namely, when we talk about invariant subspaces like joriki explained we would like to think of this as $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$ with $V_1$ and $V_2$ invariant subspaces. Now we have that $\{(10)^T\}$ and $\{(01)^T\}$ form invariant subspaces of the matrix, but how can you relate this to $V_1$ and $V_2$. I mean it does not make sense saying that $V_1=span\{e_1\}$ and $V_2=span\{e_2\}$. What I would do naturally is the following: $V=span\{a_1\} \oplus span\{a_2\} \cong span\{e_1\} \oplus span\{e_2\}$?

Comment: Does this make sense what I am doing right here? So we can basically be easy about really giving the basis and just identify it with the standard basis even if it isn't. Other representations are just equivalent so they give a 1-1 correspondence of basis elements. And even if we consider equivalent representations we just look for some $A$ such that $D=AD^\prime A^{-1}$ with $D,D^\prime$ representations of some linear map in $GL(2,K)$ in this case with respect to different bases?